# AWS ApiGateway custom domain configured in us-east-1 not working in California

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-api-gateway

I have a regional AWS ApiGateway instance configured in the `us-east-1` region with a custom domain name (`api.stage.aws.stckdapp.com`).

It's working fine accessed from Toronto, ON, Canada, but for some reason the DNS resolution is failing when tried from San Francisco, CA.

Not sure if this helps, but I also configured an AWS Route 53 health check which is also failing frequently (in different regions all over the world) with this message: `Failure: DNS resolution failed: Rcode NXDomain(3)`

I have an AWS Route 53 hosted zone set up with an A record pointing to the ApiGateway's default endpoint (`xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.`).

Comment: Could you give more details on how you created the custom domain name? Did you happen to use the API Gateway console or just added a register in Route53? Is your record an alias? Is Route53 the owner of the domain?

Comment: @palvarez both the ApiGateway custom domain name and the Route53 record were created by AWS CDK. The Route53 record is an alias indeed and `stage.aws.stckdapp.com` is a hosted zone in Route53.